# creating multiple queues with a fixed number of threads in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to create multiple event queues in Android each queue associated with a fixed number of threads.

each queue has a specific purpose and will hold the related tasks. e.g. one queue will hold all the tasks related to do the network operation, other queue requires to hold the tasks related to the disk io. My application will have a large number of these kinds tasks.

how can I accomplish this ?

As per my current understanding `ThreadPoolExecutor` can help. is my understanding correct ? if yes how can I use it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should read the article I wrote on this subject. [Managing Threads in Android](http://coopsoft.com/ar/AndroidArticle.html) Not to push my own article, it describes an open-source project (new release coming out Friday) that does just what you want.